# Continuous Stochastic Processes examples

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am trying to understand various types of stochastic processes. In order for that to happen, I needed some simple examples to be built so that I can build an intuition about them.

According to the book of [Hwei Hsu](http://webpages.iust.ac.ir/matashbar/teaching/schaum_probability.pdf) (Chapter-5, Page-161, "*Description of a Random Process*"), I can design the following simple and intuitive examples myself using only a standard die:

**2. Continuous parameter (or Continuous-time) process**

???

**4. Continuous-state process**

Suppose, we roll a die either a finite ($n$) number of times or an infinite number of times and plot $\frac{e^{X(t)}}{1000}$ as a graph like the following:

[image]

---

My first question is: are my examples correct? If not, kindly help me to make the necessary corrections.

Secondly, what would be the example of **(2)**?

Comment: This is not an example of what is asked for.  Your parameter is discrete.  What you need is something like temperature as a function of time.

Comment: @herbsteinberg how can a time be continuous if I sample it after a regular interval?

Comment: It's continuous as long as it is a function of time.  You can sample at regular or random intervals,whenever the underlying process is continuous.